# How can I determine whether a table row immediately follows a page break

Tags: vba, ms-word

Given a Word table which spans several pages, how can my code determine that a table row is the first following an automatic page break?  Note that table rows are of different heights thus a solution of the form "every 13th row is the first row on a new page" won't work.

The point of this would be to add extra text in the first cell at the top of every new page.

Comment: What is the purpose of getting that information? Can a cell span a page break? If so, does it matter for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Plus what macropod asks: Do you mean a manual or an automatic page-break? Reading your question, I'd assume the first. If I were asking the second I'd phrase the question "How to determine which table row begins on a new page"? The nuance is very important when proposing an answer for this...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `wdActiveEndPageNumber` for that table row.  Be sure that row is as big as it's going to get before checking the page number.

```
n = word.ActiveDocument.Tables(a).rows(b).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Answer (score -2):

If the table is sufficiently large that it splits over several pages then you compare the page number of consecutive rows until the page number changes. There are no pagebreaks to speak of.

Comment: Using @lobachevsky's wdActiveEndPageNumber suggestion